# Why does my Windows PC connect to the internet, but no Linux machine?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking

today we've had a couple of hardware faults due to a fire at my workplace. As a result, my main work computer does not connect to the internet anymore. I can't load a website or ping Google.com. That machine is running Ubuntu 16.04. However, using a laptop running Windows 7 I can connect to the internet, using the same ethernet cable (slowly, but it works). A Raspberry Pi running Raspbian also fails to connect, using the same ethernet cable again. Any ideas what I could try why our Sysadmin is still sleeping off the emergency night shift?

Comment: Try a different Ethernet cable?

Comment: I have, when I came in each computer was connected to its usual cable and socket. I then tried the one the laptop is hooked up to with the two linux machines to rule out the possibility of their usual sockets not working anymore due to some problem with a switch or.. hell if I know

Comment: Did the laptop have Wi-Fi access?

Comment: The Win7 one could be using a proxy? Or a different routing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that a DHCP certificate on my Linux machine is expired and the DHCP server had not been up and running again, resulting in me being the only one with no internet access.